# How to display data from multiple tables/models in a single cshtml in asp.net core .NET6 (Razor pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to asp.net core razor pages. I need to display data from multiple tables on a single page. I can only access one model class from the page. Can you please help me figure out how can I have access to multiple tables from a single page (cshtml).

I need to display User_Profile (Table/model) in Class-> create.cshtml (Class is attached to Class table by default).
Following is the code from Class -> create.cshtml

```
 @page
@model TestProject.Pages.Class.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @*<label asp-for="Class.ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class.ID" class="form-control" />*@
                @*<label asp-for="User_Profile.ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="User_Profile.ID" class="form-control" >
                    <option value="">Select Student</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Class.ID" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Class.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Class.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Class.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
           
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userprofile[0].FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userprofile[0].LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userprofile[0].ProfileType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userprofile[0].Status)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.User_Profile) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td> 
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProfileType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
           
            
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I am getting the error where I am writing  Model.User_profile. For example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.User_Profile)
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: You can attach many classes to one single class that make the view. Welcome to S.O. Please provide code not in images. Make a search and put an specific question, not so broad. Please read the guide and the tutorial on how to ask

Comment: Hi @LeandroBardelli, I hope my question is more clear now. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Typically you would have a project with an application/business logic layer. This layer will provide the data your page is requesting. So it is in this layer that you need to "glue" the different data objects together to make one single class which can then be shown in the view. Hope this helps

Comment: When did the code report the error? after submitting the form or just run the code？Can you provide your Page Model and the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**model**

```
 public class Class
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public class User_Profile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileType { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

**page model**

```
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
        {
            public Class cla { get; set; }
            public List<User_Profile> up = new List<User_Profile>()
                {
               //I write these hard-code just for testing convenience
                    new User_Profile()
                    {
                        FirstName ="mike",
                        LastName ="A",
                        ProfileType="a",
                        Status="aaa"
                    },
                    new User_Profile()
                    {
                        FirstName ="Lucy",
                        LastName ="B",
                        ProfileType="b",
                        Status="YES"
                    },
                    new User_Profile()
                    {
                        FirstName ="Nacy",
                        LastName ="C",
                        ProfileType="c",
                        Status="NO"
                    }
                }; 
    
    
            public void OnGet()
            {
                
            }
    
            public void OnPost(Class cla) 
            {
                
            }
        }
```

**page view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="cla.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="cla.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="cla.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
           
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.up[0].FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.up[0].LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.up[0].ProfileType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.up[0].Status)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.up) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td> 
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProfileType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td> 
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**page**

[image]

**when you input some value and click the submit button , you can receive it in the Post method.**

[image]

***when you want to get value from database,you can change some code like this:***

**DbContext**

```
public class Pagecontext : DbContext
    {
        public Pagecontext(DbContextOptions<Pagecontext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<User_Profile> UpTable { get; set; }
        
    }
```

**page model**

```
public class CreateModelModel : PageModel
    {
        public readonly  Pagecontext _db;
        public CreateModelModel(Pagecontext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public Class cla { get; set; }
            
        public List<User_Profile> up{ get; set; }
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            up= await _db.UpTable.ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task OnPostAsync(Class cla)
        { 
           //.......
        }
     
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Xinran, I am getting the NullException. As I need to get the values from Database where you have hardcoded them in the following line:
public List<User_Profile> up = new List<User_Profile>()
What I should replace
 new User_Profile()
                    {
                        FirstName ="Lucy",
                        LastName ="B",
                        ProfileType="b",
                        Status="YES"
                    }, 
with?

Comment: Hi @Reet,When you need to get values from database,you can use Linq to replace the hardcode,I write the hardcode just for testing convenience

Comment: Hi @Reet,I have added some new code ,you can use these new code to replace the hardcode.

Comment: Thank you very much @Xinran !! It is working now.